# Getting a random line from a file with Jmeter

Tags: load-testing, jmeter

I know that jmeter has a CSV based controller, but this will just read the lines sequentially, one per thread/iteration.

I also know that you can use
    __StringFromFile()
to read in a line from a file, but as with the CSV this reads sequentially with each thread simply taking the next line in the file.

I also know that you can use
    __FileToString()
to read an entire file into memory as a string. This should be able to be combined with
    __split()
to create an array.

My data set in this file is somewhere around 40,000 lines, one job title per line.

Is there an efficient way to be able to select a random line from the file, or will I have to read the whole thing into memory and then use array notation to select the item?

Comment: Have you considered randomly shuffling the file?

Comment: I have, which seems to be what most people do. I'm looking for a self contained solution, So I don't have to remember to shuffle the file each time, or tell others who are less technical how to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Randomizing the file BEFORE use is a much better approach.
   It will much more efficiently (especially in the case of significant amount of entries) to  randomize the order of entries in your CSV file before the test - and then read prepared data sequentially, in way you like (via CSV Data Set e.g.).
   You can do the preparation using e.g. perl script or even via [Excel Random Sorting](http://www.mrexcel.com/tip093.shtml).
2. You can also use any solution like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10196360/993246) but this will be very ineffective and resource-consuming.

Comment: If you can guarantee the records are a fixed length, you can use `java.io.RandomAccessFile` to grab exactly the record you want.  That might be faster than solution #2.  Whether it would be faster enough would depend on the amount of work each test does per iteration.  If it were me, and I was dead set against  randomly shuffling the file, I would try writing a JMeter extension that would read the entire file into memory exactly once.

Comment: The data is varied in length, but this did give me the idea for what I needed to do that will give me the best of both I think.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the answer and comments I had received what I wound up doing was:

Use a Once Only Controller with a BeanShell Sampler to read the file into an array, then when I need to pull that data I just use a BeanShell PreProccessor with:

```
import java.util.Random;
Random random = new Random();
vars.put("MyChosenVariable", vars.get("AvailChoices_" + random.nextInt(Integer.parseInt( vars.get("CounterVar")))));
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I got a simple idea just create a set of User Parameters

For example:

```
Name: dob   
User_1$: {__Random(1,28)}/${__Random(1,12)}/${__Random(1922,2000)}
```

It will return a semi-random date in the format DD/MM/YYYY for user 1.